# NGINX Configuration - Validating Request Bodies not working

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

Am following the steps from https://www.nginx.com/blog/deploying-nginx-plus-as-an-api-gateway-part-2-protecting-backend-services/ under Validating Request Bodies.

getting below exception when restart the nginx after the input request json validation

```
bind() to 127.0.0.1:10415 failed (13: Permission denied)
```

I already opened a same port inside the same server using below command,

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=10415/tcp --permanent
```

Below line is preventing from startup: api_gateway.conf

```
js_include json_validator.js;
js_set $validated json_validator;
server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:10415; # This is the error response of json_validator()
    return 415; # Unsupported media type
    include api_json_errors.conf;
}
```

Why is this? please help

Adding my full config:
**json_validated.js**

```
function json_validator(req) {
    try {
        req.log('JSON.parse exception before');
        if ( req.variables.request_body.length > 0 ) {
            req.log('JSON.parse exception inside if');
            JSON.parse(req.variables.request_body);
            req.log('JSON.parse exception inside if after parse');
        }
        req.log('JSON.parse exception inside if before return');
        req.log(req.variables.upstream);
        return req.variables.upstream;
    } catch (e) {
        req.log('JSON.parse exception');
        return '127.0.0.1:10415'; // Address for error response
    }
}
```

**api_test.conf**

```
location = /_external {
    internal;
    proxy_pass https://$validated$request_uri;
}
```

Also  tried to use $validated like this so that i can return a error based in condition below, but that does not seems to work,
Tried,
**api_test.conf**

```
  location = /_external {
        internal;
   if ($validated = "") {
        return 415; 
    }
        proxy_pass https://$validated$request_uri;
    }
```

That time am seeing below log always regarding the correct or incorrect json input,

```
2020/02/14 01:59:33 [info] 20275#20275: *2 js: JSON.parse exception before
2020/02/14 01:59:33 [info] 20275#20275: *2 js: JSON.parse exception
```

Comment: Do you have SELinux enabled?

Comment: yes it is."[root@mine]# sestatus
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
Loaded policy name:             targeted
Current mode:                   enforcing
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy MLS status:              enabled
Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
Max kernel policy version:      31"

Comment: Could you try to disable it temporary and restart nginx? `setenforce 0` as root

Comment: yes tried. Now am getting below exception and it try to connect to this api address but not throwing 415; # Unsupported media type error. Error:  failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading client request line, client: 127.0.0.1) and Upstream URI is : "https://127.0.0.1:10415/something/test"

Comment: added more config setup in original question. @IvanShatsky